# How to give permissions for one specific query

Tags: mysql, debugging, permissions

I need my db user (which is used through out the app, and **does not have root permissions**)
to be able to run `SHOW PROCESSLIST`
How would I achieve this without giving him all of root's privileges?

Comment: Does the user need to see processes for all users, or just their own?

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer - can the user issue `SHOW PROCESSLIST`?

Answer (score 0):

If the user needs to see all processes, you need to give your user the `PROCESS` privilege, otherwise I believe they should be able to issue `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and view their own.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process

Answer (score 0):

You can grant privileges in this way :

```
mysql> GRANT FILE, SELECT, SHOW VIEW, LOCK TABLES, RELOAD, SHOW PROCESSLIST, REPLICATION CLIENT ON
*.* TO 'backup_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourPassWord';
```

For more understanding, you can check : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO 'dbuser'@'%'` this will give the dbuser to do show processlist permission.